# Issue implementing embedded Derby database in eclipse project?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, derby

I'm trying to create a table, insert into the table and print the contents of the table using Derby (as shown below).

**TestProject class**:

```
package com.user.DerbyTest;

public class TestProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        db.createTable();
        db.insertIntoTable("todd", 23, 'M');
        db.insertIntoTable("wayne", 54, 'M');
        db.printAll();
    }
}
```

**DBConnection class**:

```
package com.user.DerbyTest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DBConnection {
    private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.*";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:derbytest;create=true";

    Connection conn;

    public DBConnection(){
        try {
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (this.conn != null){
            System.out.println("Connected to database.");
        }
    }

    public void createTable(){
        try {
            conn.createStatement().execute("Create TABLE MyDerbytable(Name varchar(50), Age INT, Gender char(1))");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void insertIntoTable(String name, int age, char gender){
        try {
            conn.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO MyDerbytable Values ("+name+","+age+","+gender+")");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printAll(){
        try {
            Statement statement = this.conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("Select * FROM MyDerbytable");

            while(res.next()){
                System.out.println(res.getString("Name") + res.getString("Age") + res.getString("Gender"));
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

I'm getting a whole plethra of errors when trying to to run this:

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: Changing to DROP errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your table already exits. Try DROP TABLE myderbytable;

Answer (score 0):

Your first INSERT statement will end up being:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyDerbytable Values (todd,23,M)
```

You have no quotes around the `todd` and `M` values so there are treated as references to column names giving you the error you see. You must enclose literal values like this in single quotes:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyDerbytable Values ('todd',23,'M')
```

So your insert code might be:

```java
"INSERT INTO MyDerbytable Values ('"+name+"','"+age+"','"+gender+"')"
```

(Note extra ' characters).

**But** concatenating strings like you are doing leaves you wide open to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It will also give you problems if any of your input contains a quote character. Learn about using `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I am using quotes though?  And when I change "todd" to 'todd' I get a "Invalid character constant" error. I;m more worried about just getting this bare-bones working than anything else

Comment: No you are not using quotes. Don't confuse the quotes for Java strings with the quotes that Derby requires. Added example code to answer.